kafka MirrorMaker2 - stop offset sync when consumer group idle on source cluster
I'm figuring out a way to migrate a Kafka cluster from v.2.3.0 (with Zookeper) to a new one v.3.7.1 (with Kraft). For the migration we can stop consumer/producers but without message loss. For this scope, I activated a MirrorMaker2 to copy the messages,consumer groups,offsets between the clusters. Both source and destination clusters are made by 3 nodes.
The MirrorMaker2 configuration is the following:
# specify any number of cluster aliases
clusters=source,destination

# connection information for each cluster
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs for each cluster
# for example. "A_host1:9092, A_host2:9092, A_host3:9092"  and you can see the exact host name on Ambari > Hosts
source.bootstrap.servers=kafka01.rnd.lan:9093,kafka02.rnd.lan:9093,kafka03.rnd.lan:9093
destination.bootstrap.servers=tor1kafka1-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka2-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka3-clu1.lab.lan:9093

# enable and configure individual replication flows
source->destination.enabled=true

# regex which defines which topics gets replicated. For eg "foo-.*"
source->destination.topics=GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW

offset.max.lag=1
offset-syncs.topic.location=target

refresh.topics.enabled=true
refresh.topics.interval.seconds=10

checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3

emit.heartbeats.enabled=true
emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds=10

replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy
replication.factor=3
refresh.groups.enabled=true
refresh.groups.interval.seconds=10
sync.group.offsets.enabled=true
sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds=10
emit.checkpoints.enabled=true
emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds=10


To test the solution I made the following steps:

Start producing of messages on source cluster on topic GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW
Start consuming of messages on source cluster using consumer-group-id test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109
Activating MM2

After these 3 steps, the topic and the consumer group used on source clusters are correctly generated. Moreover the offsets (current and end) correctly updates while the consumer/producers are active on source cluster :
[root@tor1kafka2-clu1.mgmt.lab.lan ~]# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server tor1kafka1-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka2-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka3-clu1.lab.lan:9093 --group test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 --describe
Consumer group 'test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109' has no active members.
GROUP                          TOPIC                           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW 0          11547 11568           21              -               -               -
[root@tor1kafka2-clu1.mgmt.lab.lan ~]# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server tor1kafka1-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka2-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka3-clu1.lab.lan:9093 --group test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 --describe
contin
Consumer group 'test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109' has no active members.
GROUP                          TOPIC                           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW 0          11566 11570           4               -               -               -
[root@tor1kafka2-clu1.mgmt.lab.lan ~]# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server tor1kafka2-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka3-clu1.lab.lan:9093 --group test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 --describe
Consumer group 'test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109' has no active members.
GROUP                          TOPIC                           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW 0          11587 11590           3               -
At this point I made the following futher steps:

Stop the consumer on source cluster
After few messages, stop the producer on source cluster.

At this point my expectation is that the current and end offset on destination cluster continue updating, so that the lag is the same on source and destination cluster, but this does not happen. Only END-OFFSET updates and the lag is more on destination cluster.
[root@tor1kafka2-clu1.mgmt.lab.lan ~]# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server tor1kafka2-clu1.lab.lan:9093,tor1kafka3-clu1.lab.lan:9093 --group test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 --describe
Consumer group 'test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109' has no active members.
GROUP                          TOPIC                           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW 0          11587 11625 38              -
This is the describe command on source cluster:
[root@kafka01.rnd.lan ~]#  /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka01.rnd.lan:9093,kafka02.rnd.lan:9093,kafka03.rnd.lan:9093 --group test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 --describe
Consumer group 'test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109' has no active members.
GROUP                          TOPIC                           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
test-consumer-kafkaupgrade-109 GEN.LAB.P.TEST.TESTINFO.OLD2NEW 0          9603 9633 30              -               -               -
As result , when I reconnect the same consumer-group on destination cluster, it consumes 8 messages that were already consumed on source cluster, see below:
Thu Oct  3 09:31:45 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:31:48 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:31:50 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:31:53 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:31:56 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:31:59 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:02 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:05 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:08 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:11 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:14 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:17 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:20 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:23 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:26 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:29 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:32 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:35 UTC 2024
^CProcessed a total of 70 messages
[siuser@ansible.lan TESTSYS]$ bash consumer_new.sh
Thu Oct  3 09:32:14 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:17 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:20 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:23 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:26 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:29 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:32 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:35 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:38 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:41 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:44 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:47 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:50 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:53 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:56 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:32:59 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:02 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:05 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:08 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:11 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:14 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:17 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:20 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:23 UTC 2024
Thu Oct  3 09:33:26 UTC 2024
Expectation: Lag should be the same between the source/destination cluster with MirrorMaker2 when producer/consumers are stopped on source cluster.

The bug was reproduced also using the same kafka version between source and cluster (v3.7.1)

I am experiencing the same issue, did you find any work around for this?
